# How to change active class for anchor Tag in Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

This is my code:

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('#programs') ? "current" : ""}}"><a href="{{ route('client.home').'#programs' }}">Programs</a></li>
```

I need to add "current" to a menu item, when user clicks on that ! I had made that for normal routes, but how to try that to an anchor tag ?

And my path is

```
example.com/#programs
```

The anchor tag is in main index page, itself - so that, i have current menu for home page as this :

```
<li class="{{ Request::path() === "/" ? "current" : ""}}"><a href="{{ route('client.home') }}">Home</a></li>
```

So, When user clicks on Home, the Home menu is getting highlighted but when user clicks on Programs - it navigates but Programs isnt gettng highlighted, instead Home is still hightlighted !

Comment: just to confirm you want to move to #progress part of  the page which has route 'client.home' when user clicks at the menu item, am I right?

Comment: No, So for instance consider my home page is ('client.home'), so when first opens up the "Home" menu will be active . And now i have menu named "Programs" and its a div anchor tag("#progress") at same home page itself. So when user clicks on Programs it needs to scroll to Programs tag ( and its perfectly working ) but how to add "current " to Program menu ( which is pointed to anchor tag ) and when scrolled down the current class should be active on Home menu !

Comment: from what you have told it can be easily achieve using jquery (or js) & html, see this [link](https://codepen.io/eksch/pen/xwdOeK) and for anchor tags you can just use id=programs & call it somewhere using $programs directly, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_href_anchor)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the **FRAGMENT** value of the example below, I have never seen a function used in laravel (thank you for writing if you see it) but php can be obtained using its function

```
parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
```

Comment: Yes and no. [URL Fragments don't get sent to the server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#116520), so if OP is attempting to process the current user request, parse_url won't work. Active state will have to happen client side.

Comment: This can be used to make js more accurate